# definition of isotopy of pants decomposition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, mapping-class-groups

What is definition of  isotopy of pants decomposition in the following paper ?

> when two pants decompositions is isotopic? Also why we say **cut system** what is definition of **system** ?

In *Hatcher, Allen; Lochak, Pierre; Schneps, Leila*, [**On the Teichmüller tower of mapping class groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.2000.028), J. Reine Angew. Math. 521, 1-24 (2000). [ZBL0953.20030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0953.20030)..

Comment: A pants decomposition is a collection of 3g-3 curves. Two pants decompositions are isotopic if the curves are isotopic to each other. "system" here is just a word for collection.

Comment: @GabrielIslambouli . So here system is equal to collection ?